# Looking for the name of an electrical component

Tags: relay, components

I am looking for a relay, but one whose output channels are always on, acting more as a permanent distributor of electricity to all connected devices, rather than an optional on/off switch to all devices.

What is the name of this component?

Comment: A piece of wire would do that. Can you be more specific how you want to distribute electricity, like connect a car battery with thick cable into some kind of fuse box where multiple smaller wires come out for separate loads?

Comment: Terminal strip?  Bus bar???

Comment: You probably mean polarised relay.

Comment: The only problem I have with multiple wiring splitting off from a single wire, is that I have too many splits ~10 for it to be split at a single point. Again a relay is perfect because the wires are separated, but the channels should be open permanently. While there are ways to solve that with a relay but that is added complexity, that I would like to avoid.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. You say you want a relay, but you also want a permanent connection. Relays are not permanent. The whole point of a relay is to be able to open and close connections based on an input signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What is the name of this component.*

A normally-closed-contact relay springs to mind. It consumes zero power in the inactive state and connects a load to the source supply. There are millions available: -

[image]

- NO means normally open
- NC means normally closed

Picture from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/io/io_5.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer, ebay only seems to sell hybrid arrays. But that is fine. BTW I assume COM/common is where the black wire will go. It was listed as the connection switching between the NO and NC so it has to be the "Ground" wie.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to distribute power from one source to many loads, with no switching, there is no need to consider using relays.

You require terminal strips or bus bars, or a collection of DIN-rail terminal blocks with bussing strips.

Here is a bus bar that might work for you (photo from Blue Sea Systems - they make a wide variety of these things.)

[image]